# Overridden tabs are not refreshing

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-action-override

I have 3 custom objects (say A, B, C), and the custom object tabs are overridden by the same lightning component, the lightning component sees which is the object (by force:hasSobjectName), and fetches a record from the object and navigates to the detail page of that record.

The problem is when I am clicking on any of these tabs (A or B or C) while I am on some another page (for example Event/Task), it is fine. But when I am on any of these tabs (say A), and clicking on another tab (B or C), it is loading the layout of A only, and when I refresh the page it loads correctly.

Checked this with 2 users, one is fine but not the other, and both are with SysAdmin profile.

Anybody faced something like this?